# jQuery .each() objects posting wrong value to ajaxurl

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

This is an adaption of pointers code from [here](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/6947539) (which is also broken in the same way in its original form there btw).

I have a number of divs on my page that are created using the code below. I can tell in outputting my objects to the console that they are all constructed properly, and all the correct elements and ids are present in each one. But somehow, when I click on the close link, what gets passed to the ajaxurl is the FIRST index on the page, then the second, etc. instead of the `pointer_id` that is part of the object clicked on and defined below. As I said, the objects in the console are perfect, with the correct values. But what gets posted is wrong.

Any ideas? The code is below.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var WPHelpPointer = {$pointers};
    $.each(WPHelpPointer.pointers, function(i) {
        wp_help_pointer_open(i);
    });
    function wp_help_pointer_open(i) {
        pointer = WPHelpPointer.pointers[i];
        $( pointer.target ).pointer( 
        {
            content: pointer.options.content,
            pointer_id: pointer.options.pointer_id,
            position: 
                {
                    edge: pointer.options.position.edge,
                    align: pointer.options.position.align,
                    nudgehorizontal: pointer.options.position.nudgehorizontal,
                    nudgevertical: pointer.options.position.nudgevertical
                },
            close: function() {
                $.post(ajaxurl, 
                    {
                        pointer: pointer.pointer_id,
                        action: 'dismiss-wp-pointer'
                });
            }
        }).pointer('open');
        console.log(pointer);
        console.log(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see where you defined the `ajaxurl`. Is that a global variable ?

Comment: yes, sorry this is defined globally. And it works to post to without issue. The problem is the value for pointer that is being sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try passing the static object as `this` using [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/):

```
close: $.proxy(function () {
    $.post(ajaxurl, this);
}, {
    pointer: pointer.pointer_id,
    action: 'dismiss-wp-pointer'
})
```